# Make text bold in xml file in android for webview

Tags: android, xml, webview

I'm using `WebView` for displaying data stored in an XML file. I have `<b></b>` tags, but the text still looks normal.

Is there any other way to make text bold?

```
 <item>
    <tag>This is <b>Bold</b> text.</tag>
 </item>
```

Comment: how are you rendering the XML document? are you using CSS, XSLT or are you just parsing it?

Comment: i'm parsing xml file using SAX parser.

Comment: Sax will treat <item>, <tag> and <b> in the same way - it doesn't know that <b> has special meaning - post some of the code you are using with SAX

Comment: after parsing data i'm sending it to webview (html file)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Answer**

```
<item>
    <tag>This is&lt;b &gt;Rice:&lt;/b&gt; text.</tag>
</item>
```

Comment: it's working..i'm using it in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rivalogic.android.shubhmuhurat&hl=en-GB this app.So please check your own code and then post comment.

Comment: i just tried it in my code and all i get is <b> xxxxx </b> not bold text, e.g. i see the tags not bold text

Comment: where you are using this?i'm was parsing xml data from xml file and i was putting that data in html code and loading that code in webview

Comment: i am loading html from asset folder with load  url